# How to use Salesforce jsforce package via a proxy, which requires a certificate and custom ca in node.js

Tags: node.js, proxy, jsforce

I'm trying to use Salesforces jsforce package in node.js via a corporate proxy which requires authentication with a cert and associated ca. Can't find a solution, any pointers out there. I can call Salesforce via its native api using axios setting the http proxy without issue.

Many thanks

i have tried setting the proxy in the jsforce connection object but it doesn't support a cert and ca.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.